# Difference between React-native and Electron

Tags: react-native, electron

I want to build a simple read-only app which should run on Android, iOS, Windows, OSX and Linux.
Does electron support mobile platform?
I couldn't figure out  which one should I go for.

Answer (score 22):

[Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) include chrome engine to render web pages as Native apps with support for different plugins to add desktop apps features.

[Electrino](https://github.com/pojala/electrino) doesn't include any render engine it uses the Safari engine on the Mac so the installation file is smaller than Electron.
There's no support for Windows yet.

React Native is using a cross-platform render to Android and iOS.

Example: `<Text>` on Android will be `TextView` and on iOS will be `UITextField`

[React Native Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) made React Native work on web

Example: `<Text>` on web will be `<p>` or `<label>` not sure
and after that, it can work on the desktop by electron

You can build universal apps by using this template by React Native code.

Also if you want a specific target you can add `component.web.js` or `.electron.js`
or `.android.js` or `.ios.js` so it will render to this target only

https://github.com/react-everywhere/re-start/tree/react-16

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at PWAs. These can be installed on almost all the major mobile and desktop platforms plus it is a web app.
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps

Answer (score 3):

Electron does not support mobile platforms, but it will be difficult to use one framework for mobile apps and computer apps.

I would recomment to use phonegap for mobile and electron for the computer application